# Get the string value that is associated with an Enum?

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum BookType
{
    Old = 'O',
    New = 'N',
    All = 'B'
}
```

What I need to do is get the value of the char in the enum.  For example if the enum is set to:

```
BookType bt = BookType.New
```

I need to get the value of new "N"

```
string val = (???)bt;
```

I need val = N

What is the best way to do this?  If it was an int easy, just cast to int.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values associated with your `enum` are still `int`s, you've just set using a character literal. If you want to recover this value as a string, you can cast the enum value to a `char` and then convert that to a string:

```
string val = ((char)bt).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast to `char`.
After casting to `char`, you'll need to call `ToString()` to convert the `char` to a `string`:

```
string val = ((char)bt).ToString();
```